# Store Git Commit IDs

Tags: git, batch-file, build, azure-devops

I've created a quick batch script to generate & store the Git commit ID for each build we run.

*Note:*
We run our builds within Azure DevOps

Current script:

```
cd C:\Projects
git show -s --format=%%H >> GitHash.txt
```

Output (CommitID):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

I want to set the name of the text file to the commit ID generated if this is possible?

Any other suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few options:

```
# Use the same command for the file name
git show -s --format=%H >> $(git show -s --format=%H).txt
```

---

```
# Store the name in variable and use it
sha1=$(git show -s --format=%H)
# OR 
sha1=$(git rev-parse HEAD)

# Write the sha to file with the desired name
echo $sha1 >> $sha1.txt
```

---

```
sha1=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
echo $sha1 >> $sha1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to overengineer, like the existing answer suggests, you can just use automatic variable:

```
Build.SourceVersion
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables